# Why an I getting Err 01 with my Canon camera and lens?

Tags: canon, aperture

So I just got a Canon Rebel T4i and I'm having trouble with my lens (18-135mm STM lens). It's when I have my camera on movie mode, when I'm setting my aperture the blades won't change. I can only set to f/3.5 and f/20, and when I keep trying to change it my camera will give me error 01. So I clean the lens contacts and when I try again, my lens makes a noise and error 01. please help. I don't know what to do...

Comment: Have you tried taking photos at different f-stops?

Comment: yes i have. it works when i take photos

Comment: please help me .

Comment: I dont have access to my T4i at the moment so i can't test it. please wait for someone else to reply or until i can test it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird canon 17-55 f2.8 IS lens error](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85579/weird-canon-17-55-f2-8-is-lens-error)

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, unless the problem is very intermittent (e.g. once a year), Err01 is almost always caused by a bad ribbon cable in the lens itself—usually the aperture ribbon.

The aperture ribbon, because of where the aperture is located, can get knocked out of position if the lens gets bumped in the wrong way, and in some situations, this can lead to the edge of the ribbon getting snagged on other moving parts inside the lens.  When this happens, the thin ribbon cable tears, and the lens cannot change its aperture.

When the camera tells the lens to change its aperture, the lens tells the aperture motor to move, and then waits for a signal from the aperture motor to tell it that it is in the right position.  If either of those two things doesn't happen, the lens doesn't tell the camera that it is in the right position, and the camera gives an Err01 indicating that it cannot communicate with the lens (when, in fact, the lens got the message).

This is, in some ways, a defect in Canon's communication protocol.  The lens should respond with a failure code after a period of time so that the camera won't lock up.  It is also, in some ways, a defect in Canon's lens design; the ribbon cable in question should be fastened more securely and in more places to ensure that it cannot ever move in a way that would allow it to get snagged.

Either way, the lens is toast, and the only thing you can do is get it repaired or replace it.

Comment: Note that in this case, it is also possible that the noise you're hearing is the sound of the aperture itself being stuck.  Either way, the cable and the aperture are one piece, so the repair is the same.

Answer (score 0):

From a simple google search of a Canon err 01, it is complaining that there is a communication error between the body and the lens.

The youtube video below, found with the simple search, might help you clean and check your lens contacts for communicating with the body.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raTT9c5uumM

Comment: Dirty contacts can be a reason, but not the ONLY reason for Err 01. It is probably something else causing the error message..